# Prove that $f(t)=\frac{\int_{1}^{b}{x^{1+t}\,dx}}{\int_{1}^{b}{x^{t}\,dx}}$ is an increasing function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $b>1$ and define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(t)=\frac{\int_{1}^{b}{x^{1+t}\,dx}}{\int_{1}^{b}{x^{t}\,dx}}.$$
I would like to prove that $f$ is an increasing function for all $t$.

Ideas so far: Certainly, it should be true, as $f$ represents the centre of mass of the region beneath the graph of $y=x^t$ over the interval $[1,b]$. So physically, it's obvious. Aside from a vague physical proof, I can show by differentiation that the derivative of $f$ satisfies  $$f'(t)=(t+1)-t\frac{f(t)}{f(t+1)},$$
But I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Thanks Gae. S. I have fixed my error.

Comment: Your physical argument can be restated in terms of statistics, since $f(t)=\Bbb EX_t$ with $X_t$ having PDF $\propto x^t$ on support $[1,\,b]$. By unitarity, increasing $t$ subtracts area under the curve from low $x$ and adds them to high $x$, and therefore increases $\Bbb EX_t$.

Comment: Thanks, J.G. That's the sort of physical argument that I had in mind (except in terms of shifting mass, rather than considering a pdf) but is there an argument that makes this more than simply intuitive?

Comment: Are you sure that $f'(t)$ exists for all $t$? It is not even obvious to me that $f$ is continuous in $t= -1,-2$

Comment: Paul Frost, it is continuous. You can get this by way of L'Hopital applied at the problem points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is an alternative proof of the log-convexity result given above by Jack D'Aurizio. Defining $g(t)=\int_{1}^{b}{x^t}\,dx$, by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality we see that
\begin{align*}
g''(t)\cdot g(t)&=\int_{1}^{b}{ x^t(\log{x})^2}\,dx\cdot\int_{1}^{b}{x^t}\,dx\\
&=\int_{1}^{b}{( x^\frac{t}{2}\log{x})^2}\,dx\cdot\int_{1}^{b}{(x^\frac{t}{2})^2}\,dx\\
&\geq \left(\int_{1}^{b}{x^t\log{x}}\,dt\right)^2\\
&=(g'(t))^2.
\end{align*}
This proves the log-convexity of $g$ and, as D'Aurizio points out, this implies that $f(t)=\frac{g(t+1)}{g(t)}$ is an increasing function.

Comment: This is perfectly fine (+1)

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I voted up yours too - not sure why anyone would do the opposite. It’s a very elegant proof!

Answer (score 0):

Key point: your $f$ is a ratio of moments.

$$g(t) = \int_{1}^{b} x^t\,dx $$
is quite trivially a continuous and positive function. $g(t)$ is midpoint-log-convex by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$ g(t_1) g(t_2) \geq g\left(\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}\right)^2. $$
By putting together the continuity and the midpoint-log-convexity we get the log-convexity of $g$, which implies that $f(t)=\frac{g(t+1)}{g(t)}$ is an increasing function, as wanted.

Comment: Jack, D'Aurizio, had to do a bit of background reading but that all chains together. That the continuity implies the log-convexity is neat.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio, below I have posted what I think is an alternative argument showing the log-convexity. I knew nothing about this until a week ago, so feel free to down vote my argument if you see an error in my reasoning!